# Align variable components with fixed width components using flex layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex layout showing some fixed-dimension cards, and it changes how many are shown in each row when you resize the window - which is great.

Now I need multiple categories of these cards, separated by a header, and I just can't get that header to align with the cards nicely. I am using a center justification and so when I set the header to be 100% it extends *too far*. want it to only go as far as the first and last cards on the first row, so that the header position changes as you resize the page as well.

I have tried different values of width and flex on the header component, but not had much luck, but I am new to most of this, so maybe there is something else you can do? I am willing to try most things that will work for a statically hosted site (using pure JS), except change the justification of the flexbox. (I can centre-justify the contents of the header, but that's a last resort).

I have a fiddle set up here: https://jsfiddle.net/6q8s1u4x/3/, but here is the basic code from that:

```css
.CardFlow {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.CardFlowHeader {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    
    /* Appearance */
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.Card {
    /* Layout */
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    
    /* Appearance */
    background-color: #6666FF;
    border-color: #000055;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="CardFlow">
  <div class="CardFlowHeader">
    <h2>My Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="Card">1</div>
  <div class="Card">2</div>
  <div class="Card">3</div>
  <div class="Card">4</div>
  <div class="Card">5</div>
</div>
```

If this jsfiddle isn't enough, I can provide screenshots later! Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Giving a different header to each card? Or having different header (for example, 1st header with 3 card, 2nd header with 2 cards)?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible with flexbox. You can't determine the width of the container by the width of the children as you require.

Comment: @alesssz, I want one header for the whole thing. I just want the header "div" to be the combined width of the cards on the first row - so that when I resize the screen, the header is always the width of the top row (Not including the empty space left and right of the cards)

Comment: @Paulie_D, That's what I'm afraid of...

Comment: Since your Card elements have fixed width, you wil lhave to create media queries to match the breakpoints at which the number of cards per row change and set the header width accordingly.